# How to distinguish if a window is being activated by mouse click?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm currently hooking window activations with the following code:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    HWND hwnd      = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wParam);

    switch (nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_ACTIVATE: // The system is about to activate a window.
    {
        return 0; // 0 - Allow 1 - Deny
    }
    }
    return 0;
```

From the docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644977(v=vs.85)

> `lParam`
> Specifies a long pointer to a CBTACTIVATESTRUCT structure containing the handle to the active window and specifies whether the activation is changing because of a mouse click.

How I could interpret the value of `lParam` and distinguish it?

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation says, for `HCBT_ACTIVATE` the `lParam` specifies a pointer to a `CBTACTIVATESTRUCT`, so simply typecast it accordingly, just like you are doing with the `wParam`, eg:

```cpp
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(
    _In_ int    nCode,
    _In_ WPARAM wParam,
    _In_ LPARAM lParam
)
{
    if (nCode < 0) return CallNextHookEx(nullptr, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    switch (nCode)
    {
        case HCBT_ACTIVATE: // The system is about to activate a window.
        {
            HWND hwnd = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(wParam);
            CBTACTIVATESTRUCT* cbt = reinterpret_cast<CBTACTIVATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
            // use hwnd, cbt->fMouse, and cbt->hWndActive as needed...
            return 0; // 0 - Allow 1 - Deny
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When activating the window by clicking in the taskbar `cbt->fMouse` returns 0,. The main reason I'm currently hooking `HCBT_ACTIVATE` is to detect when the window is activated by another window being minimized above it, do you know how I could distinguish it?

Comment: @Razec A Taskbar button *represents* a window, but is not the actual window. Activating a window by mouse refers to clicking on the window itself. AFAIK, there is no way to determine whether a window is being activated by Taskbar. But `cbt->hWndActive` should be the window that is losing focus.